# $\log\left(\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}\right)=-\frac{x^2}{2}$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I have $\log(\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda})$, where $\nu$ is the standard normal distribution and $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. Why is $$\log\left(\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}\right)=-\frac{x^2}{2}?$$

Comment: Well... because of the **definitions** of $\nu$ (once corrected) and of $\lambda$ perhaps?

Comment: See [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon-Nikodym_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$
d\nu=\exp{(-x^2/2)}\,d\lambda
$$
i.e.
$$
\nu(E)=\int_E \exp{(-x^2/2)}\,d\lambda
$$
for $E$ a Lebesgue measurable set. The measure $\nu$ is induced by the density of the standard normal.

Comment: Thanks! I have the expectation with respect to another unkown measure $\mu$ before the ln. So what I wrote above should be in brackets after $E_{\mu}$.

Comment: Except that if $\nu$ is supposed to be a probability measure, you'll want to divide by $\sqrt{2\pi}$.